# Maven warning on MacOS: Workspace defines a VM that does not contain a valid jre/lib/rt.jar

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2, maven, m2eclipse

I am trying to clean my Maven and I am getting this warning when I run mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0

[WARNING] Workspace defines a VM that does not contain a valid jre/lib/rt.jar: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home

Does any one have a clue on how to fix it?

I am on MacOS. Here is what I have configured for my eclipse:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a patch [here](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MECLIPSE-668), but it has not been applied to any release so far. :-( As a workaround you can create a symlink as described [here](http://bruehlicke.blogspot.com/2009/11/missing-rtjar-mac-os-x-using-proguard.html).

Comment: In order to make the workaround work (sic) I had to create another SYMLINK, see below:

 cd /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
 sudo ln -s /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/classes.jar rt.jar

 # ALSO NECESSSARY
 cd /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
 sudo ln -s . jre

Answer (score 2):

The answer above works, but seems to be more than what's needed.

Minimally on OSX Lion, you may get by with:

```
cd /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
sudo mkdir -p jre/lib
cd jre/lib
sudo ln -s ../../../Classes/classes.jar rt.jar
```