# Workspace defines a VM that does not contain a valid jre/lib/rt.jar: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-plugin, maven-3

I am new to maven and i have been creating simple web application with maven using hibernate, spring etc. i get following error occur when i run `mvn eclipse:eclipse` command.

```
[WARNING] Workspace defines a VM that does not contain a valid jre/lib/rt.jar: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7
[WARNING] could not read workspace project:c:\Users\Acer\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\myproject
org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParserException: processing instruction can not have PITarget with reserveld xml name (position: START_D
OCUMENT seen \r\n<?xml ... @2:7)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.MXParser.parsePI(MXParser.java:2453)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.MXParser.parseProlog(MXParser.java:1447)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.MXParser.nextImpl(MXParser.java:1395)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.MXParser.next(MXParser.java:1093)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.Xpp3DomBuilder.build(Xpp3DomBuilder.java:187)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.Xpp3DomBuilder.build(Xpp3DomBuilder.java:83)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.Xpp3DomBuilder.build(Xpp3DomBuilder.java:48)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.eclipse.reader.ReadWorkspaceLocations.readArtefact(ReadWorkspaceLocations.java:341)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.eclipse.reader.ReadWorkspaceLocations.readWorkspace(ReadWorkspaceLocations.java:536)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.eclipse.reader.ReadWorkspaceLocations.init(ReadWorkspaceLocations.java:94)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.eclipse.EclipsePlugin.getWorkspaceConfiguration(EclipsePlugin.java:2063)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.eclipse.EclipsePlugin.fillDefaultClasspathContainers(EclipsePlugin.java:1580)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.eclipse.EclipsePlugin.setup(EclipsePlugin.java:978)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.ide.AbstractIdeSupportMojo.execute(AbstractIdeSupportMojo.java:500)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
[INFO] no substring wtp server match.
```

this is my [pom.xml](http://pastebin.com/KEiNw2e5)

could anybody tell me what i am doing wrong here. thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looks like a java issue. Check your java_home directory. Is it pointing to C:\Program Files\Java\jre7 ? If so let maven also point to read same location by configure the toolchains.xml in your maven directory (e.g D:\maven-2.2.1\conf) to your java version

```
<toolchains>
<toolchain>
    <type>jdk</type>
    <provides>
        <version>1.7</version> <!--This should be same as is configured via the toolchains plugin -->
        <vendor>ibm</vendor> <!--This should be same as is configured via the toolchains plugin -->
    </provides>
    <configuration>
        <jdkHome>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0</jdkHome>
    </configuration>
</toolchain>
</toolchains>
```

Comment: i did what you have mentioned, but no luck

Comment: Are you executing this command in command prompt or in eclipse?

Comment: check if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7697387/maven-warning-on-macos-workspace-defines-a-vm-that-does-not-contain-a-valid-jre) link helps

Answer (score 5):

I was also getting the error:

> [WARNING] Workspace defines a VM that does not contain a valid jre/lib/rt.jar: C:\Program Files\Java\jre6

but I don't get the

> [WARNING] could not read workspace project:c:\Users\Acer\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources.projects\myproject

(perhaps you were not setting your workspace path up correctly on the mvn command line by using the option -Declipse.workspace=...)

Anyway, the first warning was caused by me using a JDK in a non-standard place (JAVA_HOME=C:\tools\java\jdk1.6.0_31) and setting my Eclipse workspace up to use that as the default.  The Maven Eclipse plugin does not seem to choose the default JDK correctly, The "mvn eclipse:eclipse" would not work until I removed the JDK in "C:\Program Files\Java\jre6" from the list of installed JDKs within Eclipse.  I only have the correct one in the list now.

Answer (score 1):

Add your own JRE, remove the default JRE installed in Eclipse. Yeah, it works.I could get no warning information when typing the command mvn eclipse:eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me maven fails to parse Eclipse's workspace settings properly. I was hitting the warning, and then I removed all JREs (I had two JREs and one JDK under Window-Preferences-Java-Installed JREs) and left only the JDK. No warnings since.

Answer (score 0):

Try to store your maven projects in a directory that is not your eclipse workspace then import the projects to eclipse (without copying it!). Now the mvn eclipse:eclipse should work without warnings.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Java 8, and I found that every time I did the eclipse:eclipse it was changing the JRE to JavaSE-1.7 instead of the JavaSE-1.8.

After more review of a bare bones pom.xml I saw the line in my properties section for maven.compiler.source and maven.compiler.target pointing to 1.7.  Once I changed that to 1.8 everything works as expected.

I also have multiple version of Java setup.  That didn't seem to be a problem.  Updating this line seemed to do the trick, no more warnings when I do eclipse:eclipse now.

Hope it helps.